# Posting arrays from client side to firebase database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a fantasy - soccer web-app. I am currently stuck on trying to create a function that sends a 6 player array from the client side to the firebase database.

I have tried:

```
  $scope.history = [];

    $scope.saveTeam = function(){

  var ref2 = firebase.database().ref("users/" + uid + "/week");
  var ref3 = $firebaseArray(ref2);
  ref3.$add({
  "players": $scope.history    
  });
   $location.path('/mySquad');
   };
```

and this works. But this is not quite what I am looking for. I would prefer to use the `set()` function so that each game week simply replaces the previous week's selection.

However, when I use `set()` instead of `$add`, the function does not work. There is no change in the database. Is there a way to send the 6 player array to my database?